# Running MR program with separate mapper, reducer and driver classes

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

maxtempmapper.java class:

```
    package com.hadoop.gskCodeBase.maxTemp;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;


public class MaxTempMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable> {
    private static final int MISSING=9999;

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable kay,Text value,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        String year = line.substring(15,19);
        int airTemperature;
        if(line.charAt(87)== '+'){
            airTemperature=Integer.parseInt(line.substring(88, 92));
        }else{
            airTemperature=Integer.parseInt(line.substring(87, 92));
        }
        String quality=line.substring(92,93);
        if(airTemperature !=MISSING && quality.matches("[01459]")){
            context.write(new Text(year), new IntWritable(airTemperature));
        }
    }

}
```

maxtempreducer.java class:

```
 package com.hadoop.gskCodeBase.maxTemp;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;



public class MaxTempReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<IntWritable> values,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException {
        int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for(IntWritable value : values){
            maxValue=Math.max(maxValue, value.get());
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(maxValue));
    }

}
```

maxtempdriver.java class:

```
    package com.hadoop.gskCodeBase.maxTemp;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;


public class MaxTempDriver extends Configured implements Tool{
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception{
        if(args.length !=2){
            System.err.println("UsageTemperatureDriver <input path> <outputpath>");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

         Job job = Job.getInstance();
         job.setJarByClass(MaxTempDriver.class);
         job.setJobName("Max Temperature");

         FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
         FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(args[1]));

         job.setMapperClass(MaxTempMapper.class);
         job.setReducerClass(MaxTempReducer.class);

         job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
         job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

         System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1); 
         boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
         return success ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         MaxTempDriver driver = new MaxTempDriver();
         int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(driver, args);
         System.exit(exitCode);
         }


}
```

I have to execute the above three classes on single node hadoop cluster on windows using command prompt
can someone please help me in how to execute these three classes on command prompt(windows)?

Answer (score 0):

Archive all the java files into a single .jar file. Then just run it as you normally do. In Windows, it's easier to run Hadoop via Cygwin terminal. You can execute the job by the following command:

```
    hadoop jar <path to .jar> <path to input folder in hdfs> <path to output folder in hdfs>
```

Eg:

```
    hadoop jar wordcount.jar /input /output
```

**-UPDATE-**

1. You should assign you driver class to the job.setJarByClass(). In this case, it would be your MaxTempDriver.class
2. In eclipse, you can create a jar file by right clicking on your source folder > Export > JAR file. From there you can follow the steps. You can set your Main Class during the process as well.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: So which classname should i provide in the job.setJarByClass()? Can you also explain how do I archive all the java files mapper, reducer and driver in one jar using eclipse? @mfmz